# What's the distance between two circumcenters

Tags: geometry, circles

This problem was came to a Facebook post of mathigon ......the problem seems trickier than I expected...can you help me to find the distance??[image]

Comment: I am not sure there is a closed form for the answer, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: There is clearly a solution - look at half the intersection.

Comment: @Moti Yes, there is a solution, but (for example) the problem $$\frac{\pi}{3} = x - \sin(x)$$ also has a solution.  It's just that expressing the solution is no walk in the park.

Comment: So you provide an estimate based on the equation. It seems that the question was about getting the equation.

Comment: @Henry: In fact, there is a 
[closed form (sort of)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3470709/122782),
it is $\sqrt{1+\mathbf{d}}-\sqrt{1-\mathbf{d}}
\approx 0.807945506599$,
where $\mathbf{d}\approx 0.73908513321516$
is known as 
[the Dottie number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number), 
[A003957](http://oeis.org/A003957).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $\angle CAB = \angle ABC = \angle BAD = \angle DBA = \theta$

Area of the $\bigtriangleup CAD = \frac{1}{2} 1^2 \sin 2 \theta = \frac{1}{2} \sin 2 \theta$

Area of the sector $CAD$ (consider the right side of the circle on the left) $ = \frac{1}{2} 1^2 2\theta = \frac{1}{2} (2 \theta)$

So the common area between the circles $ = 2 (\frac{1}{2} (2 \theta) - \frac{1}{2} \sin 2 \theta)$

However, it is given that the common area between the circles $= \frac{\pi}{2}$

Hence we need to solve the following equation for $\theta$

$$2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \theta \right) - \frac{1}{2} \sin 2 \theta \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Solving, $\theta = 1.15494$

Finally length of $AB$ is $2 \cos \theta = 0.80794684217$

Answer (score 0):

The area of the lens formed by two overlapping circle of radius $r$ and at distance $d$ apart is
given by https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lens.html

$$Area= \pi r^2-2r^2 \tan^{-1}\frac d{\sqrt{4r^2 -d^2}}-\frac12d \sqrt{4r^2 -d^2}
$$
Set $Area =\frac\pi2$ and $r=1$ to obtain numerically $d= 0.8079$.